# Dism wim export and split different hashes

Tags: windows, images, dism

I have a rather weird question.

I am in the process of creating bootable media/ images and I noticed every time I split a .wim into smaller .swm files the file hashes change for the .swm file every single time. So say I split-image from the win to install.swm twice none of the 4 exported files match hashes when they are identical.

Additionally I noticed That if I export A source index, say I only want windows 11 pro the hash changes every single time using dism /export-image sourceindex:1… the original wim is the same and came directly from Microsoft’s download servers. Is there a reason for this?? Metadata? The way it splits the files is different every time??

So if I export the first source index 10 times the filehash is different every time even though nothing else is changing.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the resulting swm files as regarding size and content?

Comment: WAG: Perhaps sections are written in differing order? Perhaps internal files and folders have a time-stamp that updates? Diff the files.

Comment: @harrymc The size and the file/folder amount is the same exact values the only thing that is different when I do Get wim info is the time stamp of modification. I tried to change the time stamp of the files to the same and they still differ.

Comment: @drmoishepippik I think maybe that is what Is happening I was Able to recreate this issue on new vms I thought that time stamps do not change the hash of the file but maybe I’m wrong. If I do a full list out of all the folders in the wim they seem like the same order

Comment: Since the files are compressed, the archive has the file *metadata* stored in it, such as creation and modification date. BTW, this date/time-dependence is used in SSH, so that one could not simply record a conversation from the middle and play part back at a later date. A site at which I worked had an issue that two computers could ping and FTP files, but SFTP failed -- because one server's clock was off by 1 hour due to Daylight Savings Time issues.

Comment: @Stevenerberg: Have you tried a binary compare of the files?